# My fetch request fails from a print state in flask/react app

Tags: reactjs, flask

I am useing Flask/React and in some point my login request start to fail and raise status code 500.

I am useing custom decorator to validate reqeust schemas and he looks like this

```
def validate_schema(schema_name):
    def wrapper(func):
        def decorated_func(*args, **kwargs):
            data = request.get_json()
            print(data)
            schema = schema_name()
            errors = schema.validate(data)
            if errors:
                raise Unauthorized(errors)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_func
    return wrapper
```

This `print(data)` use only for developing. So in some point i find the problem is this print and when i remove it everytings was fine.

Try to make the reqeust from postnal and there came this as error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 268, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 268, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 467, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 84, in view
    return current_app.ensure_sync(self.dispatch_request)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 582, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Coding\Urban\server\Flask-SoftUni-Project\util\decorators.py", line 11, in decorated_func
    print(data)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

In some point everyting works super fine and just like that stop working. Only login request faling form the whole app.
So is there someone with idea how one print can be a problem, what i am not understand? :/

PS. From that moment debuggin logs from the console gones. (Try to restart the pycharm but is the same problem)
PS. Debugger is active